# What are the New Gestures for the Microsoft Multi-touch Mice?

Tags: windows-8

Some time ago, Microsoft promised that it would add new functionality to its family of multi-touch mice once Windows 8 was released. Now that Windows 8 has gone GA, what are the new gestures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### New Gestures

Below are the new actions that come with Windows 8, along with their default gestures

- Switch Between Recent Apps (two fingers right)
  [image: Switch Between Recent Apps Animation]
- Open Recent Apps
  [image: Open Recent Apps Animation]
- Snap App Left/Right
  [image: Snapp App Left/Right Animation]
- Show/Hide App Commands (two fingers up/down)
  [image: Show/Hide App Commands Animation]
- Open Charms (two fingers left)
  [image: Open Charms Animation]
- Search
- Share
- Start Screen
- Devices
- Settings
- Home
- End
- Page Up
- Page Down

### All Gestures

Below is a table of the the old and new gestures, and their possible arrangements.

[image: Table of Microsoft Touch Mouse Gestures]